# Is the gravitational field $\mathbf{g}(x)=-G\int_{\Bbb R^3}\rho(y)\frac{x-y}{|x-y|^3}\,\mathrm{d}y$ continuously differentiable?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mathematical-physics, gauss-law

I apologize for mathematician-style question, but I was wondering if for continuous mass density $\rho:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ with compact support, the gravitational field $$\mathbf{g}(x)=-G\int_{\Bbb R^3}\rho(y)\frac{x-y}{|x-y|^3}\,\mathrm{d}y$$ would be continuously differentiable. Of course, it is not too hard to show that the divergence is defined, $$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g}=-4\pi G\rho$$ but I have only managed to show that this is true in the sense of distributions, that is to say, for smooth bump functions $\varphi\in C^\infty_{\mathrm c}(\Bbb R^3)$, $$\langle\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g},\varphi\rangle:=-\langle\mathbf{g},\nabla\varphi\rangle = \langle -4\pi G\rho,\varphi\rangle$$ where $\langle,\rangle$ is the usual function inner product, and $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g}$ is defined abstractly as some functional. But does the formula $$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{g}=-4\pi G\rho$$ actually hold classically?

Comment: Suggestion: rewrite the convolution to make $y/\|y\|^3$ appear, then go to spherical coordinates, and remark that the apparent pole at $y=x$ in your formula for $g(x)$ was spurious.